# SQL: Find the biggest percentage change in response time

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics

I'm trying to calculate and list the websites in order of biggest overall reduction in response time from one time period to the next.

I don't strictly need to use a single query to do this, I can potentially run multiple queries.

websites:

```
| id | url                    |
| 1  | stackoverflow.com      |
| 2  | serverfault.com        |
| 3  | stackexchange.com      |
```

responses:

```
| id | website_id | response_time | created_at |
| 1  | 1          | 93.26         | 2014-01-28 11:51:39
| 2  | 1          | 99.46         | 2014-01-28 11:52:38
| 2  | 1          | 94.51         | 2014-01-28 11:53:38
| 2  | 1          | 104.46        | 2014-01-28 11:54:38
| 2  | 1          | 85.46         | 2014-01-28 11:56:38
| 2  | 1          | 100.00        | 2014-01-28 11:57:36
| 2  | 1          | 50.00         | 2014-01-28 11:58:37
| 2  | 2          | 100.00        | 2014-01-28 11:58:38
| 2  | 2          | 80            | 2014-01-28 11:58:39
```

Ideally the result would look like:

```
| percentage_change | website_id | 
| 52                | 1 | 
| 20                | 2 |
```

I've got as far as figuring out the largest response time, but no idea how to do another query to calculate the lowest response time and then do the math, then sort the maths.

```
SELECT * FROM websites
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT distinct * 
       FROM responses
       ORDER BY response_time desc) responsetable
ON websites.id=responsetable.website_id group by website_id
```

Thanks

Comment: And how are you defining the biggest change in response time?

Comment: By "response time from one time period to the next" do you mean difference between consecutive requests or within a given time period? Shouldn't the result for website_id = 1 in your example be 100 - ((50/104.46) * 100) = 52% ?

Comment: @michalkralik I think I mean, difference from the first recorded sample until now. Yes, will update sample answer.

Comment: To me, it's still unclear how exactly you define the biggest change. If the consecutive values for a site were 10s, 2s, 1s would the answer be 80% or 90%?

Comment: @Bugs not consecutive change, just the % change between the biggest and smallest response times

Comment: @Tom Thanks. Could you also explain why all but 1 record in the responses table have id=2 and why both results in your result table have website_id=1?

Comment: @Bugs: It's all dummy data which I typed out for the question. The data in the responses table was suppose to represent that there could be an unknown QTY of responses for each site (or none at all). Both results having website 1 is a typo by me, sorry if that's caused confusion will fix :)

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. And what result would you expect if there were no reduction, e.g. the consecutive values were 1, 2, 3?

Comment: @Tom . . . The date/time stamps are the same for the last three rows.  How do you distinguish the order?  Can I assume that there are milliseconds not shown in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a couple of sequence numbers:-

```
SELECT a.id, a.url, MAX(100 * (LeadingResponse.response_time - TrailingResponse.response_time) / LeadingResponse.response_time)
FROM
(
    SELECT website_id, created_at, response_time, @aCnt1 := @aCnt1 + 1 AS SeqCnt
    FROM responses
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT @aCnt1:=1
    ) Deriv1
    ORDER BY website_id, created_at
) TrailingResponse
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT website_id, created_at, response_time, @aCnt2 := @aCnt2 + 1 AS SeqCnt
    FROM responses
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT @aCnt2:=2
    ) Deriv2
    ORDER BY website_id, created_at
) LeadingResponse
ON LeadingResponse.SeqCnt = TrailingResponse.SeqCnt
AND LeadingResponse.website_id = TrailingResponse.website_id
INNER JOIN websites a
ON LeadingResponse.website_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.url
```

SQL fiddle for this:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ace08/1

EDIT - different way of doing it. This will only work if the id on the responses table is in date / time order.

```
SELECT a.id, a.url, MAX(100 * (r2.response_time - r1.response_time) / r2.response_time)
FROM responses r1
INNER JOIN responses r2
ON r1.website_id = r2.website_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT r1.website_id, r1.id, MAX(r2.id) AS prev_id
    FROM responses r1
    INNER JOIN responses r2
    ON r1.website_id = r2.website_id
    AND r1.id > r2.id
    GROUP BY r1.website_id, r1.id
) ordering_query
ON r1.website_id = ordering_query.website_id
AND r1.id = ordering_query.id
AND r2.id = ordering_query.prev_id
INNER JOIN websites a
ON r1.website_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.url
```

You could do a similar thing based on the response_time field rather than the id, but that would require the response_time for a website to be unique.

EDIT

Just seen that you do not just want consecutive changes, rather just the highest to lowest response. Assuming that the lowest doesn't have to come after the highest:-

```
SELECT id, url, MAX(100 * (max_response - min_response) / max_response)
FROM
(
    SELECT a.id, a.url, MIN(r1.response_time) AS min_response, MAX(r1.response_time) AS max_response
    FROM responses r1
    INNER JOIN websites a
    ON r1.website_id = a.id
    GROUP BY a.id, a.url
) Sub1
```

If you are only interested in the lower response time being after the higher one:-

```
SELECT id, url, MAX(100 * (max_response - min_following_response) / max_response)
FROM
(
    SELECT a.id, a.url, MAX(r1.response_time) AS max_response, MIN(r2.response_time) AS min_following_response
    FROM responses r1
    INNER JOIN  responses r2
    ON r1.website_id = r2.website_id 
    AND (r1.created_at < r2.created_at
    OR (r1.created_at = r2.created_at
    AND r1.id < r2.id))
    INNER JOIN websites a
    ON r1.website_id = a.id
    GROUP BY a.id, a.url
) Sub1
```

(assuming that the id field on the response table is unique and in created at order)

Answer (score 5):

You need the equivalent of the `lag()` or `lead()` function.  In MySQL, I do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select website_id, max(1 - (prev_response_time / response_time)) * 100
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.response_time
              from table t2
              where t2.website_id = t.website_id and
                    t2.created_at < t.created_at
              order by t2.created_at desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_response_time
      from table t
     ) t
group by website_id;
```

EDIT:

If you want the change from the highest to the lowest:

```
select website_id, (1 - min(response_time) / max(response_time)) * 100
from table t
group by website_id;
```

Comment: Having some trouble getting this running, which t and t2 values need to be swapped to real table names? Could you throw this into a SQL Fiddle. Thanks

Comment: Both t and t2 alias' will be for the responses table

Comment: Note that the percentage calculation is slightly wrong. Change it to max((((prev_response_time - response_time) / prev_response_time)) * 100) . Note that this does rely on the the date / time being unique (2 response rows for a web site with the same date / time will be compared with the response with the previous time, not the one with the same time but a previous id).

Comment: @Kickstart . . . I fixed the formula for the reduction calculation, but the problem was the subtraction, not the division.  Look at `id` 2 in the data (the results comes from 20 = `(1 - 80/100)*100`, which is `(1 - prev/current)*100.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - both your updated version and mine give the same results but after that it is a matter of preference. Yours gets the the previous as a fraction of the current and then subtracts that from 1. Mine gets the change as a fraction of the previous. That said from the updates it now appears the OP is only interested in the change from the highest to the lowest, irrespective of one immediately following the other.

Answer (score 1):

From your "I've got as far as figuring out the largest response time, but no idea how to do another query to calculate the lowest response time and then do the math, then sort the maths." I understant that you want smallest response time and largest response time and do your math.

```
    drop table #test
 create table #test(
 id int, website_id int, response_time decimal, created_at datetime)
insert into #test (id , website_id , response_time , created_at) values ( 1  , 1          , 93.26, '2014-01-28 11:51:39')
insert into #test (id , website_id , response_time , created_at) values ( 2  , 1          , 99.46         , '2014-01-28 11:52:38')
insert into #test (id , website_id , response_time , created_at) values ( 2  , 1          , 94.51         , '2014-01-28 11:53:38')
insert into #test (id , website_id , response_time , created_at) values ( 2  , 1          , 104.46        , '2014-01-28 11:54:38')
insert into #test (id , website_id , response_time , created_at) values ( 2  , 1          , 85.46         , '2014-01-28 11:56:38')
insert into #test (id , website_id , response_time , created_at) values ( 2  , 1          , 100.00        , '2014-01-28 11:57:38')
insert into #test (id , website_id , response_time , created_at) values ( 2  , 1          , 50.00         , '2014-01-28 11:58:38')
insert into #test (id , website_id , response_time , created_at) values ( 2  , 2          , 100.00        , '2014-01-28 11:58:38')
insert into #test (id , website_id , response_time , created_at) values ( 2  , 2          , 80            , '2014-01-28 11:58:38')

select * from #test
select distinct  MINT.website_id,MINT.MINRT,maxT.MINRT,(MINT.MINRT/maxT.MINRT)*100--Do your calculation here---
from #test t0
inner join(select min(response_time) as MINRT,website_id from #test   group by website_id  )  MINT
 on  MINT.website_id = t0.website_id
inner join(select max(response_time) as MINRT,website_id from #test   group by website_id  )  maxT
 on  maxT.website_id = t0.website_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to divide the minimum response time by the maximum response time per website? That would simply be:

```
select 
  websites.id as website_id, 
  100 - min(response_time) / max(response_time) * 100 as percentage_change
from websites
left join responses on websites.id = responses.website_id
group by websites.id;
```

(I assume response_time can never be zero. In case it can, you will have to use a case statement for that.)

Answer (score 0):

Group the response times by `website_id`, find `MIN(response_time)` and `MAX(response_time)` and compare whether `MIN()` happened after `MAX()` to filter only websites which improved their performance.

```
<?php
$rows = $db->fetchAll('
    select
      r.website_id, min(r.response_time) min_time, max(r.response_time) max_time,
      (select
         rmin.created_at
       FROM
         responses rmin
       WHERE
         rmin.response_time = min(r.response_time) AND
         rmin.website_id = r.website_id
       ORDER BY rmin.created_at
       LIMIT 1) min_created_at,
      (select
         rmax.created_at
       FROM
         responses rmax
       WHERE
         rmax.response_time = max(r.response_time) AND
         rmax.website_id = r.website_id
       ORDER BY rmax.created_at DESC
       LIMIT 1) max_created_at
    FROM
      responses r
    GROUP BY
      r.website_id');

foreach($rows as $row) {
    if($row['max_created_at'] < $row['min_created_at']) {
        echo 'Website '.$row['website_id'].
                ' improved by '.
                (100 - (($row['min_time'] / $row['max_time']) * 100)).
                "%\n";
    }
}
```

The query will be however most probably pretty slow with large datasets. You'll have to optimize the indexes and/or query.
sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa8f9/8